# Incompatible pointer to integer conversion 'int' with an expression of type 'id'

Tags: ios, int, nsdictionary

In my app I am retrieving data from a MySQL database using JSON.

One of the table fields is idCategoria, from type integer. Now I am trying to assign the idCategoria value to a int variable in my app, but this showing a compiler warning. I have logged the value for categoriaID an it is 143913536 but should be 1.

This is the warning shown:

```
Incompatible pointer to integer conversion initializing 'int' with an expression of type 'id'
```

And this is how I am trying to do this:

```
 int categoriaID = [categoriaDescription objectForKey:@"idCategoria"];
```

Comment: The compiler diagnostic means that you're trying to assign a pointer ("id") to an integer.  If you check the spec for NSDictionary you will see that it ALWAYS returns an object (or nil), never a "scalar" (such as an `int`), and you can't (legitimately) assign a pointer to an `int`.  So what you get from the dictionary is an NSNumber object, and you need to extract its value with the `intValue` method.

Comment: `NSString` also has an `intValue` method.  There are possibly other Foundation classes as well.  And certainly likely that there are custom classes out there with an `intValue` method.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Try:

```
int categoriaID = [[categoriaDescription objectForKey:@"idCategoria"] intValue];
```

Comment: Perfect.  I just used this in comparing a boolean defaults value from an NSButton checkbox: `if ([[defaults valueForKey:@"dnd"] intValue]==1)`